# c++ swap global and local vector？

Tags: c++, swap

I want to swap a global vector and a local vector, and my question is the local vector is on he stack.The swap operator will exchange two vector by pointer, so after swap, the global vector will point to the local vector, which is on stack.

**When leave the scope, the local vector will be released**, I know the contents of the vector is swaped, but `y` is on stack, and why `x` is still valid after leave `func` scope, `y` will realeased after that. How is this done?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

vector<int> x = {2, 3, 4};

void func() {
    vector<int> y = {1, 2, 3};
    cout << "y before: " << &y << endl;
    x.swap(y);
    cout << "y after: " << &y << endl;
}

int main()
{
    cout << "x before: " << &x << endl;
    func();
    cout << "x after: " << &x << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What exactly did you mean by "why does the following code still work"? What does "still work" mean? What did you expect to happen?

Comment: I know the contents of the vector is swaped, but y is on stack, and why x is still valid after leave func scope, y will realeased after that. How is this done?

Comment: Why wouldn't it be "valid after leave func"? It's still an object in global scope. Swapping its contents does not change that. Only objects in local scope, namely `y`, get destroyed after the function scope has ended.

Comment: After swaped, does the `x` then point to `y`'s contents in stack?

Comment: @dahohu527 `x` doesn't point anywhere because `x` is not a pointer.

Comment: `x` contains the former contents of `y`. `x`'s location does not change. If you swap the engine in Toyota with an engine from a Honda, and then the Honda (with the Toyota's engine) gets driven away, you still have a Toyota next to you with the Honda's engine inside it. Nothing has happened to the Honda engine. It's still in the Toyota, after it's swapped.

Comment: Thank you for your patient answers! I know swap use std::move to improve the speed, then if we use `x = std::move(y)` I wondor how to improve the speed, and how the memory is allocated

Comment: You might be thinking about this backwards.  A _move_ is normally implemented with a _swap_, not the other way around.  There are no specifications about the state of `y` after a move-assignment like above, except that it must still be destructible.  So it's actually undefined behavior to use `y` after it has been move-assigned to another object.  Because you are struggling with the fundamentals in C++, you should abandon this mindset of aiming for speed.  You're likely to waste time optimizing the wrong thing.  Focus on learning the basics and building up your understanding of the language.

Answer (score 4):

*"The swap operator will exchange two vector by pointer"* -- the implementation details of `swap` are not really your concern.  But you do seem to be confused about which pointer is being swapped (if any).

I can say for certain that the *pointer* `&y` is *not* what's being swapped.  Your `func()` call will display exactly the same pointer value before and after the swap because `y` is an object on the stack.  Likewise for `&x` which points to an object at global scope level.

Internally to the `vector`, the actual memory storing the values will probably be swapped because both vectors share the same (default) allocator and therefore it's allowed to simply switch pointers for efficiency.  But the actual vector object holding them definitely does not switch positions in memory.

If you want to check whether the internal memory is swapped, then you can output the pointer returned by the `data()` member function:

```
cout << "x before: " << x.data() << endl;
x.swap(y);
cout << "x after: " << x.data() << endl;
```

Comment: Thx for your answer! I know the contents of the vector is swaped, but `y` is on stack, and why `x` is still valid after leave `func` scope, `y` will realeased after that.

Comment: Are you saying that after this explanation you don't understand the difference?  Then I think you need to try writing your own simple vector class and you'll probably get it.  `x` is valid because its lifetime is at global scope level.  It doesn't matter _what_ `y` contains -- `y` is destroyed when `func()` exits.  Let's say there is a pointer swap happening inside the vector -- that means that the two objects trade the memory that they are managing.  That memory is allocated on the heap and is not subject to stack rules.  Each object still manages one block of memory each.

Comment: I understand that the `x` itself is above the heap, and `y` is on the stack. I can simplify the swap as follows `x = std::move(y)`, std::move will modify the pointed the data. If `y`'s data is on stack, and std::move will take `x`'s data point to `y`'s data, So the question is does std::move do something special?

Answer (score 2):

The swap function being called is std::vector::swap.  This function swaps the contents of the vectors.

Your calls to cout print the addresses of the vectors. When each of the calls is made, the variables whose addresses are being printed are still valid.

Vector y is allocated on the stack, but the elements of both vectors are allocated on the heap.  After the swap, vector x points to the elements originally allocated for vector y.  When vector y is removed from the stack, the elements originally allocated for vector x are deleted.

Answer (score 2):

I see some confusion so I suggest you to change your mindset:

- from thinking in terms of stack/heap/global into thinking in terms of [storage duration](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/storage_duration)
- from thinking in terms of pointers to thinking in terms of objects, resources and ownership

### Storage Duration

> All objects in a program have one of the following storage durations:
>
> - ***automatic*** storage duration. The storage for the object is allocated at the beginning of the enclosing code block and deallocated
>   at the end. All local objects have this storage duration, except those
>   declared static, extern or thread_local.
> - ***static*** storage duration. The storage for the object is allocated when the program begins and deallocated when the program
>   ends. Only one instance of the object exists. All objects declared at
>   namespace scope (including global namespace) have this storage
>   duration, plus those declared with static or extern.
> - ***thread*** storage duration. [...] (since C++11)
> - ***dynamic*** storage duration. The storage for the object is allocated and deallocated per request by using dynamic memory
>   allocation functions.

`x` has static storage duration. This means that `x` is alive and valid for the entire duration of the program.

`y` has automatic storage duration. This means that the object is "alive" for the duration of the enclosing code block. The object begins its life at the beginning of the code block and ends its life at the end of the code block. In this case the code block is the body of the function. An `y` object will be alive during a function call.

This is true regardless of the type of the objects or the operations you do on `x` and `y`. If `x` and `y` are integers, vectors, strings, pointers, enums or really anything doesn't change this in any way, shape or form. No matter what operations you do with them (swap, clear, assignment, copy, move, ...) the above remains unchanged: `x` is valid to access for the entire duration of the program and `y` is valid to access while the object it denotes is alive (as stated above).

### Object, resources, ownership

`x` and `y` are `std::vector` objects. They have the storage duration as stated above.

Each `std::vector` may have one or more objects that they are responsible for. For instance a `std::vector<T>` with 3 elements has and is responsible for: 1 memory object where it holds its elements and 3 `T` objects. These objects have dynamic storage duration.  The storage for these objects is allocated and deallocated at request by the `std::vector` object. `std::vector` is the owner of these objects. It is responsible for creating/destroying these objects.

### Your example

`x.swap(y)`: as stated above no operation will change the storage duration of `x` and `y`. After this operations you have the same object `x` as before (except it has a different content) and the same object `y` as before (except it has a different content). What this operation does is a transfer of ownership between the two vectors of their resources. During this operation the memory and element objects that were owned by `x` change ownership to `y` and the memory and element objects that were owned by `y` change ownership to `x`.

So after you exit the function `func`:

You you most definitely can still access `x` because the object `x` is alive for the entire runtime of the program (it has static storage duration). The function call cannot change that.

### Your program control flow

Let's break the control flow of your program:

- `vector<int> x = {2, 3, 4};`: as part of the static initialization the static storage object `x` is created. As part of its initialization it creates and assumes ownership of some needed resources (1 memory resource and 3 elements, which I collectively call `{2, 3, 4}` from now on) (these resources are objects with dynamic storage duration: they were created at request and will be destroyed at request by their owner)
- `func()` call

  - `vector<int> y = {1, 2, 3};`: the object `y` is created with automatic storage duration; as part of its initialization it creates and assumes ownership of some needed resources (memory and elements, which I collectively call `{1, 2, 3}` from here on now) (these resources are objects with dynamic storage duration: they were created at request and will be destroyed at request by their owner)
  - `x.swap(y)` call:

    - the resources previously owned by `x` (`{2, 3, 4}`) change ownership to `y`
    - the resources previously owned by `y` (`{1, 2, 3}`) change ownership to `x`
  - `}` (end of function): the automatic storage duration object `y` exits its scope. As part of its destruction it requests the destruction of the resources it owns; at this point it owns `{2, 3, 4}` so these get destroyed. `y` gets destroyed. From this point on it is illegal to access `y` or `{2, 3, 4}` because their lifetime has ended.
- in main, after the `func()` call: `x` is valid (it has static storage duration) and it owns `{1, 2, 3}` (the resources it "stole" from `y`).
- after main, before the end of the program: the static storage object `x` is destroyed. As part of its destruction it requests the destruction of the resources it owns: `{1, 2, 3}`

Answer (score 1):

> *"The swap operator will exchange two vector by pointer, so after swap, the global vector will point to the local vector, which is on stack."*

No, the swap operator (likely) will exchange **the data** of the two vectors "by pointer", so after the swap, the global vector will (internally) point to the local vector's **former data**, which is on the **heap**.

The above is not an entirely accurate statement, but it does highlight the main shortcoming of the question's statement. The other inaccuracies (such as assuming that "the stack" and "the heap" are useful descriptions) are minor in comparison. Somewhere along the line, the idea of exchanging pointers to *the data of* two vectors morphed into the idea of exchanging pointers to two vectors, and the result was misunderstanding.

---

Typically, a vector consists of a pointer to the elements of the vector plus some bookkeeping data. The swap exchanges the pointers (and the bookkeeping), which causes the data to be exchanged for a fixed cost, no matter how large the vector is.

Here is part of a possible vector implementation, focusing on the pointers that get swapped.

```cpp
// Abridged outline of a possible vector implementation
template <class T, class Allocator>
class vector {
    T* data;   // Could (should) be a smart pointer instead of a raw one.
    // Other data members

  public:
    void swap(vector & other)
    {
        swap(data, other.data);   // Swap pointers.
        // Swap other data members.
    }

    // Other functions
};
```

The pointers *inside* the vectors are swapped in this implementation, not pointers to the vectors. (Other implementations might have different implementation details.)